# Redirect http domain and http subdomains to https versions

Tags: nginx

I am using nginx to host my site on DigitalOcean, my app can support both domain and subdomain requests.

Here is how the domain directs should work:

`http://example.com` -> `https://example.com`
`http://www.example.com` -> `https://example.com`
`http://subdomain.example.com` -> `https://subdomain.example.com`

The subdomain part is dynamic so I cannot fix the subdomain name in my nginx config file.

This is what I currently have in my nginx conf file.

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name www.example.com;
    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}
server {
        #listen 80;
        #listen [::]:80;
        listen 443 ssl;

        root /var/www/example.com/public;

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.php index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name example.com;
        #rewrite ^/(.*) https://example.com/$1 permanent;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
        }

        # other stuff no relevant here
}
```

I've managed to get the first rule working, however I couldn't get the second and third rule working:
`http://subdomain.example.org` -> `https://subdomain.example.org`, it seems to go to `https://example.org` instead.

`http://www.example.org` -> `https://example.org`, goes to `https://www.example.org`

Comment: Do you set HSTS headers to include subdomains?

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have a configuration block for `subdomain.example.org`, nginx uses your `default_server` block when serving request to the subdomain. In that block, the redirect rule sends request to `https://example.com`.

I would use a configuration like this:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    return 404;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    return 301 https://example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    server_name *.example.com;

    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

First `server` block makes sure the server returns 404 to requests to non-existing virtual hosts.

Second block handle redirect for main domain and third block handles redirects for subdomains.

Additionally you need the blocks for the `https` virtual servers.